# Why do I need to explicitly specify which global secondary index when using DynamoDB query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-dynamodb

I am using Aws::DynamoDB::Client to perform the query on a table. I have defined multiple global secondary indices, one of which uses `user-id` and `recorded_at`.

When I run the query with the following query parameters:

```
dynamo_query = {
          expression_attribute_values: {
            ":l1" => start_time.to_i,
            ":l2" => end_time.to_i,
            ":u1" => user_id
          },
          key_condition_expression:    "user_id = :u1 AND recorded_at BETWEEN :l1 AND :l2",
          table_name:                  table_name,
          limit: 50,
        }
```

It complains about Query condition missed key schema element: company_id

It only works when I explicitly specify the global secondary index name in the query like this:

```
dynamo_query = {
          expression_attribute_values: {
            ":l1" => start_time.to_i,
            ":l2" => end_time.to_i,
            ":u1" => user_id
          },
          key_condition_expression:    "user_id = :u1 AND recorded_at BETWEEN :l1 AND :l2",
          table_name:                  table_name,
          index_name:                  'UserIdRecordedAtIndex',
          limit: 50,
        }
```

Why is this the case? Shouldn't dynamo auto pick up the correct GSI based on the query parameters passed?

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB doesn't have a Query Optimiser like a relational database. You must explicitly state which index you use at run-time. This ensures no time is lost optimizing queries at run time.

What happens if you define only the partition key for your Query. How would DynamoDB know which index to search from if you had more than one index with the same partition key but different sort key.

What if you were doing a Scan, how would DynamoDB know which index or table it is you want to read from as there are no keys present.

Comment: Hm I find that a little odd. It only accepts two query parameters at the most, one being hash key and the other being range key, how much time can it really lose by matching just those two? Isn't it really just O(n), or really in practice O(1)? 

But appreciate the quick answer!

Comment: Yes that's fine when you provide the PK and SK. Most people use Query only provide the PK. You could have 5 or 6 destinations able to fulfill that request, how would DynamoDB know which one you'd like to have your results ordered by?